# Interactive Mandelbrot Set generator

Tags: java, multithreading, fractals

The purpose of this project is to generate an interactive Mandelbrot Set with smooth coloring. The user can interact with the W, A, S, D keys to move around and with + and - to zoom in and out. It divides the height of the window into multiple sections and uses threads to paint each section. It also paints on a BufferedImage first, and then the 2D Graphics paint the JPanel.

I would like to know what improvements could be made to boost its performance and code readability. Respecting OOP principles is also something I'm interested in.

**MandelbrotSet.java**

```
package com.flak231;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MandelbrotSet extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    protected static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 1080;
    protected static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 900;
    private static final double ZOOM_FACTOR = 0.9;
    private static final int OFFSET_FACTOR = 40;
    private Image image;
    private double offsetX;
    private double offsetY;
    private double zoom;
    private boolean stateChanged = true;

    MandelbrotSet(String title){
        super(title);
        image = new BufferedImage(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        offsetX = -0.7;
        offsetY = 0.0;
        zoom = 0.004;
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // Nothing here yet
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        stateChanged = true;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            offsetY -= OFFSET_FACTOR * zoom;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            offsetX -= OFFSET_FACTOR * zoom;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            offsetY += OFFSET_FACTOR * zoom;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            offsetX += OFFSET_FACTOR * zoom;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS) {
            zoom *= ZOOM_FACTOR;
            repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS) {
            zoom /= ZOOM_FACTOR;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Nothing here yet
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        MandelbrotSet ms = new MandelbrotSet("Mandelbrot Set");
        ms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        ms.getContentPane().add(ms.new MandelbrotPane());
        ms.setSize(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        ms.setResizable(false);
        ms.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private class MandelbrotPane extends JPanel{

        private void updateImage() {
            int numberOfThreads = 100;
            int step = IMAGE_HEIGHT / numberOfThreads;
            List<ImageSlicePainter> threads = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; i += step) {
                threads.add(new ImageSlicePainter(zoom, offsetX, offsetY, image, i, Math.min(i + step, IMAGE_HEIGHT)));
            }
            for (ImageSlicePainter imageSlicePainter : threads) {
                imageSlicePainter.start();
            }
            try {
                for (ImageSlicePainter imageSlicePainter : threads) {
                    imageSlicePainter.join();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            if(stateChanged) {
                updateImage();
                stateChanged = false;
            }
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ImageSlicePainter.java**

```
package com.flak231;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageSlicePainter extends Thread{
    protected static final int MAX_ITERATIONS = 255;
    private double zoom; 
    private double offsetX;
    private double offsetY;
    private Image image; 
    private int minY;
    private int maxY;
    private Color[] colorSet;

    public ImageSlicePainter(double zoom, double offsetX, double offsetY, Image image, int minY, int maxY){
        this.zoom = zoom;
        this.offsetX = offsetX;
        this.offsetY = offsetY;
        this.image = image;
        this.minY = minY;
        this.maxY = maxY;
        colorSet = new Color[MAX_ITERATIONS + 1];
        //fill the color array with colors generated by taking i into consideration
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            colorSet[i] = computeColor(i);
        }
    }

    void updateImageSlice() {
        double real = (0 - MandelbrotSet.IMAGE_WIDTH / 2.0) * zoom + offsetX;
        double imagStart = (minY - MandelbrotSet.IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2.0) * zoom + offsetY;
        for (int x = 0; x < MandelbrotSet.IMAGE_WIDTH; x++, real += zoom) {
            double imag = imagStart;
            for (int y = minY; y < maxY; y++, imag += zoom) {
                int value = computeMandelbrot(real, imag);
                ((BufferedImage)image).setRGB(x, y, colorSet[value].getRGB());
            }
        }
    }

    private Color computeColor(int iterations) {
        /*
        To obtain a smooth transition from one color to another, we need to use
        three smooth, continuous functions that will map every number t.
        A slightly modified version of the Bernstein polynomials will do, as they are
        continuous, smooth and have values in the [0, 1) interval.
        Therefore, mapping the results to the range for r, g, b is as easy as multiplying
        each value by 255.
        */
        double t = (double)iterations / (double)MAX_ITERATIONS;
        int r = (int)(9 * (1 - t)*t*t*t * 255);
        int g = (int)(15 * (1 - t)*(1 - t)*t*t * 255);
        int b = (int)(8.5*(1 - t)*(1 - t)*(1 - t)*t * 255);
        return new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    private int computeMandelbrot(double startReal, double startImag) {
        double zReal = startReal;
        double zImag = startImag;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX_ITERATIONS; counter++) {
            double r2 = zReal * zReal;
            double i2 = zImag * zImag;
            if (r2 + i2 > 4.0) {
                return counter;
            }
            zImag = 2.0 * zReal * zImag + startImag;
            zReal = r2 - i2 + startReal;
        }
        return MAX_ITERATIONS;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateImageSlice();
    }
}
```

[image: The beauty of fractals]

Answer (score 4):

```
private Color[] colorSet;
```

in `public class ImageSlicePainter` is an instance property, and the
(256) colors are computed each time an instance of `ImageSlicePainter`
is created, that is 100 times (the number of threads) for each image update.

With a *static* property the colors are computed only once in the runtime of the program:

```
public class ImageSlicePainter extends Thread {

    // ... 
    private static Color[] colorSet = computeColors();

    private static Color[] computeColors() {
        Color[] colorSet = new Color[MAX_ITERATIONS + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            colorSet[i] = computeColor(i);
        }
        return colorSet;
    }

    private static Color computeColor(int iterations) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

An alternative approach to achieve a “smooth” transition between consecutive colors would be to use the “HSB color model” (also called [“HSV“](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)), where the
 [“hue”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue)component is used to describe the angular position of the color on a color wheel.

In your case the hue can be chosen as the ratio

```
 float t = (float)iterations / (float)MAX_ITERATIONS;
```

plus an optional offset, for example:

```
private static Color computeColor(int iterations) {
    if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS) {
        return Color.black;
    } else {
        float blueHue = 2.0f/3.0f;
        float t = (float)iterations / (float)MAX_ITERATIONS;
        return Color.getHSBColor(t + blueHue, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, having the color set as static probably saved a lot of computation time.